# Wsus cleanup wizard

Tags: wsus

If i ran the wsus server cleanup wizard. and i remove the computers not contacting the server for more than a month.

if the computers contact the server again will it re-appear in the wsus console

Comment: Which version of WSUS?

Comment: wsus version 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they should reappear, and you then move them to whatever groups you have organized in WSUS (like for us we have an "approved for rollout" group to get updates).

Comment: +1, they definitely do come back. Also, if you have a pre-configured computer group (via Group Policy) they will automatically put themselves in it.